# レンタルサーバ (Render) にホストしたアプリに独自ドメイン名を設定したい

Tags: render.com

私は Ruby on Rails を使ってアプリを開発しており、このアプリを将来的にいろんな方に使っていただきたいと考えています。現在はレンタルサーバのRenderを使っているのですが、ドメイン名にレンタルサーバの名前が入っています。

具体的には `https://tsunageru.onrender.com` から `https://tsunageru.com` にしたいのですが、レンタルサーバの名前が入っていないサイトをアップしている方は独自のサーバーからアップしているのでしょうか？

それともレンタルサーバでも料金によって消せるのでしょうか？

質問の仕方が分かりづらくて申し訳ありません、サーバなどに関しての知識が疎いので、教えて頂けたら幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

ここに書かれています
https://render.com/docs/custom-domains

まず知りたい機能を英語でググるのが良いです。
英語がわからなかったら質問を機械翻訳してググると良いです。
https://translate.google.com

Comment: これは名前.comでhttps://tsunageru.comを取得すればドメインの設定から変更を行えるという事でしょうか？

Comment: 使いたいドメインを持っていないのであれば、レジストラから取得する必要があるのはその通りです。レジストラは多数あるので利用する前に「レジストラ 比較」などで検索してレビューを確認するのがよいです。

Answer (score 0):

インターネットのプロトコルは IP アドレスを基礎にしたものになっていて、通信の初手でドメイン名からそれに対応づいている IP アドレスを調べる処理から入ります。 つまりどこかでドメイン名と IP アドレスの組が管理されているわけです。

その仕組みは DNS と呼ばれているので仕組みの詳細は DNS という言葉で検索してみてください。 ここで全容を説明するには複雑すぎます。

ドメイン名を登録する手続きとしてはドメイン名を管理している業者 (レジストラ、またはその代理店) に依頼すればよく、業者にもよりますが `.com` 直下のドメイン名であれば年間 1000 円前後の費用が相場だと思います。

`onrender` のサブドメインは `onrender` が権限を持っているので `onrender` のサービスと一体で提供されているのでしょうが、 `.com` については `.com` について権限を持っているところに依頼しないといけません。 日本では[お名前.com](https://www.onamae.com/)などが有名だと思います。

サーバの物理的な実体はレンタルでもクラウドでも、またはあなたが自宅で動かしても基本的には問題はありません。 (インターネットの仕組みの上では問題ありませんがプロバイダや回線事業者によってはサーバ運用を制限していることもありますので契約上の制限がある場合もあります。) サーバ側で独自ドメインに対応するいくらかの設定は必要ですが大抵のレンタルサーバは対応していると思います。